# I cant display a temp on a lcd display. Because it wont let me put the part where it updates the lcd and displays it the temp

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

When I try to run the code it comes up with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 35, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Here's the code that I'm trying to run.

```
import framebuf
import os
import time
import lcd
import machine
import utime
 
BL = 13
DC = 8
RST = 12
MOSI = 11
SCK = 10
CS = 9
 
 #lcd prep
if __name__=='__main__':
    # Setup the LCD display
    pwm = PWM(Pin(BL))
    pwm.freq(1000)
    pwm.duty_u16(32768)#max 65535

    lcd_display = lcd.LCD_2inch()
#temp 
sensor_temp = machine.ADC(4)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535)

while True:
    reading = sensor_temp.read_u16() * conversion_factor 
    temp = 27 - (reading - 0.706)/0.001721
    print(temp)
    utime.sleep(2)
    
lcd_display.fill(lcd_display.black)
lcd_display.text(temp, 0, 0, lcd_display.white) #heres where there error sends me to
lcd_display.show()
```

- [Here's the screen I'm using](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-LCD-2#Python_example)
- [This is what I'm basing my code off of.](https://how2electronics.com/read-temperature-sensor-value-from-raspberry-pi-pico/)

Comment: It seems you have to convert `temp` to a string before passing it to `lcd_display.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code you're trying to imitate, you will see this line:

```py
    oled.text(str(round(temperature,2)),50,8)
```

In your case, you're doing something similar, only with a different display. You could try:

```py
lcd_display.text(str(round(temp,2)), 0, 0, lcd_display.white)
```

This rounds the value of `temp` to 2 decimal places, and converts it to a string, before sending that string to the LCD.